# Django error: "settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value."

Tags: python, django

I am trying to follow the guide [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/multi-db/) for using multiple databases in Django 2.2, with the default database left blank.  In my settings.py file I have

```
# Set database routers
DATABASE_ROUTERS = [r'myapp.db_routers.AuthRouter', r'myapp.db_routers.RemoteRouter']

# Database configuration - leave default blank
DATABASES = {
    'default': {},
    'auth_db': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    },
    'remote': {
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'HOST': 'MY HOST NAME',
        'NAME': 'MY DB NAME',
        'PORT': 'MY PORT NAME',
        'USER': get_secret(Secrets.REMOTE_DB_USERNAME),
        'PASSWORD': get_secret(Secrets.REMOTE_DB_PASSWORD),
        'OPTIONS': {
            'driver': 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server',
            'host_is_server': True
        }
    }
}
```

My db_routers.py file then contains the two database routers, as suggested in the documentation (but it should capture all of the django built-in apps):

```
class AuthRouter:
    route_app_labels = {"admin", "sessions", "messages", "staticfiles", "auth", "contenttypes"}

    def db_for_read(self,
                    model: Model,
                    **hints) -> Optional[str]:
        if model._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels:
            return "auth_db"
        else:
            return None

    def db_for_write(self,
                     model: Model,
                     **hints) -> Optional[str]:
        if model._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels:
            return "auth_db"
        else:
            return None

    def allow_relation(self,
                       model_1: Model,
                       model_2: Model,
                       **hints) -> Optional[bool]:
        if (model_1._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels or
                model_2._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels):
            return True
        else:
            return None

    def allow_migrate(self,
                      db: str,
                      app_label: str,
                      model_name: Optional[str] = None,
                      **hints) -> Optional[bool]:
        if app_label in self.route_app_labels:
            return db == "auth_db"
        else:
            return None


class RemoteRouter:

    remote_db = "remote"

    def db_for_read(self,
                    model: Model,
                    **hints) -> Optional[str]:
        # raise ValueError("read")
        return self.remote_db

    def db_for_write(self,
                     model: Model,
                     **hints) -> Optional[str]:
        # raise ValueError("write")
        return self.remote_db

    def allow_relation(self,
                       model_1: Model,
                       model_2: Model,
                       **hints) -> Optional[bool]:
        # raise ValueError("allow relations")
        if (model_1._state.db == self.remote_db or
                model_2._state.db == self.remote_db):
            return True
        else:
            return None

    def allow_migrate(self,
                      db: str,
                      app_label: str,
                      model_name: Optional[str] = None,
                      **hints) -> Optional[bool]:
        # print(f"allow migrate: {db}, {app_label}, {model_name}")
        return True
```

However, when I run showmigrations I get the error "settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value.".  I have tried only using "auth" and "contenttypes" in my first database router as per the documentation, but that didn't help.  I've also looked at other questions with the same error on here, but I can't find any having the same issue with the database routers.

Comment: Maybe not all apps in your application are captured by the router?

Comment: @LucasMoeskops I assumed that my RemoteRouter would just pick up the remaining apps that AuthRouter doesn't - I might be misunderstanding how this works though